# "Solve" command with a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, solver

I have a problem with the equation shown below. I want to enter a vector in `t2` and find the roots of the equation from different values in `t2`.

```
t2=[10:10:100]
syms x
p = x^3 + 3*x - t2;
R = solve(p,x)
R1 = vpa(R)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy! Don't use `syms` and use [the general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Algebraic_solution):

```
t2 = [10:10:100];

%p = x^3 + 3*x - t2;
a = 1;
b = 0;
c = 3;
d = -t2;

D0 = b*b - 3*a*c;
D1 = 2*b^3 - 9*a*b*c + 27*a^2*d;
C  = ((D1+sqrt(D1.^2 - 4*D0.^3))/2).^(1/3);

C1 = C*1;
C2 = C*(-1-sqrt(3)*1i)/2;
C3 = C*(-1+sqrt(3)*1i)/2;

f  = -1/(3*a);
x1 = f*(b + C1 + D0./C1);
x2 = f*(b + C2 + D0./C2);
x3 = f*(b + C3 + D0./C3);
```

Since `b = 0`, you can simplify this a bit:

```
% ... polynomial is the same

D0 = -3*a*c;
D1 = 27*a^2*d;

% ... the different C's are the same

f  = -1/(3*a);
x1 = f*(C1 + D0./C1);
x2 = f*(C2 + D0./C2);
x3 = f*(C3 + D0./C3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trial>> syms x p

Trial>> EQUS = p == x^3 + 3*x - t2

It is unknown that you want to solve an equation or a system.
Suppose that you want to solve a system.

Trial>> solx = solve(Eqns,x)

But, I do not think you can find roots.
You can solve one equation.

Trial>> solx = solve(Eqns(3),x)

As far as I know, Maple can do this batter.

Answer (score 0):

In general, loops should be avoided, but this is the only solution that hit my brain right now.

```
    t2=[10:10:100];
    pp=repmat([1,0,3,0],[10,1]);
    pp(:,4)=-t2;
    for i=1:10
    R(i,:) =roots(pp(i,:))';
    end
```